# Cylinderical Shell Calculus Question

Tags: calculus

How should i solve this?

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume V generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis.

y = $19x^2$, $y = 0$ , $x=1$

I Know I have to Use the Formula $V = \int_{a}^{b}2\pi x f(x)dx$
But i am confused How should i use it..

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding cylindrical shells versus disks/washers is to compare the axis of rotation with the axis of integration.  In other words, if the easier (i.e., more tractable or convenient) variable of integration is along a particular axis, say the $x$-axis, and the axis of rotation is *perpendicular*, then you will use cylindrical shells.  If the axis of rotation is *parallel* to the axis of integration, then you will use a disk/washer method, the disk method being a special case of washers.

That said, if you know you will use cylindrical shells, then consider a representative cylindrical shell, whose radius is some value $r$ between the limits of integration $[a,b]$.  Then for that radius, the height of the shell is some function of that radius; i.e., $h = f(r)$.  The differential thickness of the shell is $dr$.  So its differential volume $dV$ is approximated by a rectangular slab of width $2\pi r$ (the circumference of the shell), height $h = f(r)$, and thickness $dr$:  $$dV = 2\pi r \times f(r) \times dr.$$  Integrating the differential volume over the range of the radius $r \in [a,b]$ yields the total volume:  $$V = \int_{r = a}^b 2\pi r f(r) \, dr.$$  Notice I used $r$ instead of any particular axis name because we sometimes will integrate with respect to $y$ and sometimes with respect to $x$ depending on the axis of rotation.

So, the first two equations you are given, $y = 19x^2$ and $y = 0$, indicate the *height* of the shell as a function of its radius.  Since you are rotating about the $y$-axis, it is implied that the lower limit of integration is $x = 0$; the upper interval is given as $x = 1$.  Therefore, $f(x) = 19x^2 - 0 = 19x^2$, and the desired integral to be evaluated is $$V = \int_{x=0}^1 2\pi x (19x^2) \, dx.$$

What if we did something more complicated?  Suppose we want to find the volume of the region bounded by the same curves, again rotated about the $y$-axis, but this time the lower limit of integration is $x = 1/2$.  Then the integral becomes $$V = \int_{x = 1/2}^1 2\pi x (19x^2) \, dx.$$

Now what if, in addition, the lower curve is not $y = 0$, but $y = -x$?  Then the resulting height function is $f(x) = 19x^2 - (-x) = 19x^2 + x$, and the integral becomes $$V = \int_{x=1/2}^1 2\pi x (19x^2 + x) \, dx.$$

Finally, what happens if we *move* the axis of rotation?  Suppose instead of rotating about the $y$-axis (i.e., $x = 0$), we rotate about $x = -1$?  Then we must be careful to remember the formula for the volume as a function of the radius $r$, rather than an axis.  Here, the radius begins at $1 + \tfrac{1}{2} = \tfrac{3}{2}$, and ends at $1 + 1 = 2$.  But the height as a function of this radius is not simply $19r^2 + r$:  it should be $19(r-1)^2 + (r-1)$, because $r = 1+x$, and the height was specified as a function of the $x$-value.  So the volume in this case can be written as $$V = \int_{r = 3/2}^2 2\pi r (19(r-1)^2 + (r-1)) \, dr.$$  Alternatively, you can write it as $$V = \int_{x = 1/2}^1 2\pi (x+1) (19x^2 + x) \, dx,$$ which you can see either by doing the substitution, or by interpreting it geometrically.

I **strongly recommend** as an exercise that you sketch the solids described by all four scenarios I outlined above:  (1) the original question; (2) modifying the lower limit so the solid now has a hole; (3) changing the height function by altering the lower surface; and (4) shifting the axis of rotation which increases the inner and outer diameters.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's find the domain over which to integrate:
$$y=0=19x^2 \implies x=0$$
Since the upper bound is already in terms of $x$, we are done: $[0,1]$
Now, we set up the integral:
$$V=\int\limits_a^b 2\pi x y dx$$
$$\int\limits_0^1 2\pi x (19x^2) dx =38 \pi \int\limits_0^1 x^3 dx =38\pi \left[\frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^1=\frac{38\pi}{4}$$
$$=\frac{19\pi}{2}$$

Comment: To be clear, this is correct in the sense that one must plug this $f(x)$ into the integral in the OP, and one is not simply integrating $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$.